# IPN Listner not working MVC3

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My IPN listner is not working.when i tried with IPN listner Error is showing as follows "We're sorry, we could not send an IPN."
But i can access the IPN Handler url  from browser.

here is my IPN handler Code.

```
  public ActionResult IPN()
    {
        LogMessage ("entering ipn action ");
        var formVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        formVals.Add("cmd", "_notify-validate");

        string response = GetPayPalResponse(formVals, true);
        LogMessage ("IPN Response received: " + response + " <-- That was response. . . ");

        if (response == "VALID")
        {
            LogMessage("Response Was Verified");
        }

        else
        {
            LogMessage("RESPONSE WAS NOT VERIFIED");
        }

        return Json("Sucess",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

 string GetPayPalResponse(Dictionary<string, string> formVals, bool useSandbox)
    {
        string paypalUrl = useSandbox
                                ? "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
                                : "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(paypalUrl);

        //Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(strRequest);

        foreach (string key in formVals.Keys)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", key, formVals[key]);
        }
        strRequest += sb.ToString();
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        string response = "";
        using (StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            streamOut.Write(strRequest);
            streamOut.Close();
            using (StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: I'm also getting "We're sorry, we could not send an IPN." from the IPN Simulator for IPN url, I think Paypal's site may just be having issues at the moment?

Comment: Having the same problem. Can communicate via external IP address. MVC5 project using an Async HTTP handler. I have a breakpoint that is never ever hit.

Comment: Day 3 : Still no word back on my Paypal support ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had faced same issue before I feel it may be because your MVC Application may be published in shared hosting environment Then you have to follow some step to to make MVC RC application works 
Here is the blog which help me to solve the issue.Please check this

http://helpnshareidea.blogspot.in/2013/11/mvc3-applications-in-windows-shared.html

Comment: Thank you lab5connect..you really saved me..Thanks a lot